USB SuperSpeed Interface Connections
In USB SuperSpeed interface Hub device , Checklist document, Figure 4-3, page 5,
In the figure 4-3, it is showing like, DC blocking Capacitors are placed on Tx and Rx differential signals.
But on Figure 4-5, DC Blocking capacitors are placed on only Tx differential lines. Any idea on the reason behind this?

4.3 is how you connect two chips.
4.5 is how you connect a chip to a connector.
The reason is that transmit pins on all devices are AC coupled to cable, and receive pins on all deviced connect directly to cable. So in all devices the transmit/output is AC coupled.

Oh Ok. So, based on Figure 4.5, since the Rx lines don't have DC Blocking capacitors, it is assumed that the device on the other side of the type-C connector would be connected to Tx, right? And hence, on the other side of the connector, these lines would be having the DC Blocking capacitors. Thanks! :)

Latest USB3 specifications do recommend to place DC-blocking caps in both Rx and Tx path, Rx is optional.
